# wordpress custom pre-fixed templates

Tags: wordpress, templates

I want to create a page template that has a pre-fixed css. Lets say I name it page-sevencol.php then I know that the content will have a fixed width and a specific style and so on. My pages have different layouts thats why I need to create these kind of templates.

Is it possible? if so how? Ive looked in the wp codex and it does not seem to have the answer. Please take a minute to help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you seem to need just a limited set of templates. The question is: do you want to apply them automatically? Basically, there are two techniques to apply a template to a page (or post or custom post, etc.) in WordPress.
**First method:** using the template naming convention to get the template automatically applied to a page (or post) with the same name. 
In this case, you create a page page-mynewpage.php and this template will automatically get applied to your page named /mynewpage/.
**Second method:** you create a template by creating a page (let's say : template1.php) and declaring it as a template with a comment at the top of the page:

```
/**
 * Template Name: Template1
*
*/
```

This template will now be selectable inside the admin of WordPress to be applied to any page:

[image: The Template dropdown in WordPress Admin]

So if **A)** you only need a limited set of templates & **B)** are ok to select them on a per-page basis in the admin, this is your solution. You would just need to create as many pages as you need templates, not forgetting to include the comments that declare them as templates and using a different name each time.

If you need your templates to be applied dynamically, then we need more info about the logic to use for select each template...

**EDIT :** That is it, Abel (just read your comment). Your page is mainly generated with 4 elements: header.php, sidebar.php, footer.php and another page to produce the content, but this page is different depending on where you are in the site. If you are on a page, it will be, by default, page.php. If you are reading a post, WordPress will by default use single.php.

To apply all your different templates, just go and open page.php in your theme folder. Save it under another name, like page-template7cols.php. Insert a comment like I just explained above, so this template will show in your admin next time you create a new page. Adapt it the way you want (changing the HTML / PHP and therefore adapting the way the content of the page will be displayed). Do the same for your other 9 templates.

Then, everytime you create a new page, just start by selecting the proper template in your dropdown (see previous screen capture). And whenever you will make a change to page-template7cols.php, for example, the changes will be reflected on all pages for which you have selected this template.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it all, the thing is that I have like 40 pages that uses the like 10 different layouts so I want to create 10 templates that allows me to just paste in my html when creating a new page in the admin panel. I know how to declare new templates and the header.php sidebar.php and the footer.php are all fine, its only the content area I'm not sure about. How to I write the code to show my content the right way.. Everything is working except this part and I'm getting really frustrated..

Comment: I posted an answer can you please check, I appreciate you helping me seriously

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
  Template Name: Template1
 */
  <?php get_header(); ?>
   <div class="content-wrap sevencol clearfix">
<div class="row clearfix">

    <div class="content">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
         <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

              <?php the_content(); ?>

               <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                     </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
      <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It seems fine. Just do not forget to close the first two divs you have opened just after `get_header()`! (Except if you have decided to close them in footer or sidebar).

Comment: @barakadam so this could work then? maybe name the template page-sevencol.php and use it for the pages that use  <div class="content-wrap sevencol clearfix"> (and yes I close the other tags in sidebar)

Comment: Abel, the name you give to your page, in this case, does not matter. You are creating templates that are declared with the comment on the top. So you will need to select Template1 in the dropdown menu of the admin in WP when creating a page. So if you want to use a useful name, put it there, in the comments, replacing "Template1" with "7 columns page", for example.  Then yes, any page that you apply it to will have the `<div class="content-wrap sevencol clearfix">`. Well done.

Comment: @barakadam Finally ive been at it for 2 days now, never used worpress before.. Thank you so much.. cant belive I finally got my fixed templates :D

Comment: Good luck for the rest. Glad I could help